# How to reduce the space between the dropdown menu items?

Tags: html, css

I created a navbar menu which has a dropdown list each nav item. I would like to reduce between each dropdown menu item vertically.

I already set the padding and margin of the li, ul and li a to 0px but it didn't change.

```css
ul li ul li a {
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

li {
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul li:hover>ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul:hover {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 90%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li nav-item>
    <a href="#">NAV ITEM 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <img src="#">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">NAV ITEM 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <img src="#">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">NAV ITEM 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">DROPDOWN MENU ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <img src="#">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can see some space between the dropdown menu item vertically and would like to reduce it so it only has enough space vertically for the items.

Comment: What space are you seeing? That's as close as it can get, you can reduce the line-height to make the li's collapse in more, or use negative margins. I suspect your issue is with the spacing that is actually part of the typography of your font.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce spacing of li elements with line-height property, for example in you case 22px will get li items very close.

```
ul li ul li {
  line-height:22px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've determined that padding is still present, you can experiment to determine the proper amount needed. Mark as important if possibly referenced elsewhere to enforce the new spacing.

```
    #NAV ul.nav li a {
    padding: 8.5px !important;
    }
```